# How to create a "TempMute" command?

Tags: discord.js

How to create a TempMute command for discord.js which supports the command handler from [An Idiot's Guide](https://anidiots.guide/first-bot/a-basic-command-handler).
I understand you need to use `.addRole()`, but I have no idea how to create it with a timer. The range of the timer needs to be from 60 to 15 minutes.

Comment: My base code will not paste here due to not reading it correctly. Don't know why.

Comment: To post code, you can first paste it, then select it and click the `{}` button (CTRL+K will work as well). If the code is too long, please consider reducing it to the most important parts. If it's still too long you might consider uploading it to an external platform like pastebin, but that should be your last choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an action to be executed after some time, you need to use [`setTimeout()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp). Here's an example:

```js
// If the command is like: -tempMute <mention> <minutes> [reason]
exports.run = (client, message, [mention, minutes, ...reason]) => {
  // You need to parse those arguments, I'll leave that to you.

  // This is the role you want to assign to the user
  let mutedRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "Your role's name");
  // This is the member you want to mute
  let member = message.mentions.members.first();

  // Mute the user
  member.roles.add(mutedRole, `Muted by ${message.author.tag} for ${minutes} minutes. Reason: ${reason}`);

  // Unmute them after x minutes
  setTimeout(() => {
    member.roles.remove(mutedRole, `Temporary mute expired.`);
  }, minutes * 60000); // time in ms
};
```

This is just a pseudo-code, you'll need to parse the arguments and get the role.